# Ошибка: SQL logic error near "insert": syntax error"

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Выдаёт ошибку:  SQL logic error
near "insert": syntax error"
Вот код:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbName.Text != "" && tbSurname.Text != "")
        {
            SQLiteCommand CMD = DB.CreateCommand();
            CMD.CommandText = "insert into Personal(FIO) values(@Name, @Surname)" +
                              "insert into Personal(Age) values(@Age)" +
                              "insert into Personal(group_DY) values(@DY)" +
                              "insert into Albuminus(FIO) values(@Name, @Surname)" +
                              "insert into Revealing(FIO) values(@Name, @Surname)" +
                              "insert into Blood_B(FIO) values(@Name, @Surname)" +
                              "insert into Blood_A(FIO) values(@Name, @Surname)" +
                              "insert into KT_B(FIO) values(@Name, @Surname)" +
                              "insert into KT_A(FIO) values(@Name, @Surname)";
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = tbName.Text.ToUpper();
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@Surname", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = tbSurname.Text.ToUpper();
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@Age", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = tbAge.Text.ToUpper();
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@DY", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = tbDY.Text.ToUpper();
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: печальная структура бд однако)

Insert into table (your, some, fields) values(your, some, values)
в этом ошибка.Если указываешь в какие поля вставлять, то должен указать столько же полей для вставки значений

Comment: @SultanovShamil Ответы - в ответы. А то лучше тогда закрыть как "вызван опечаткой/не воспроизводится".

Comment: Не заносит в саму базу данных. А почему печальная структура. Не понял немного: А то лучше тогда закрыть как "вызван опечаткой/не воспроизводится"

Comment: Не помогает, что тогда делать?

Comment: Что именно "не помогает"? Нажмите кнопку "править" и добавьте в вопрос новый код, чтобы было понятно, что именно вы правили. У вас две ошибки: не совпадает число полей и отсутствует точка с запятой после каждой команды. Структуру базы мы не видим, поэтому и код никто не приводил, оставив это вам на исправление.

Comment: Замечание о плохой структуре базы очень простое. Нет необходимости создавать две таблицы, в одной из которых хранить  имя, в другой - возраст. Создайте одну таблицу Person, в которой будут поля FirstName, LastName, Age. Почитайте о приведении таблицы к третьей нормальной форме, это поможет. Вам нужно научиться строить таблицы в 3НФ, чтобы потом понимать, что иногда для производительности таблицы денормализуют.

Answer (score 1):

У вас две ошибки: не совпадает число полей и несколько команд в одной.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbName.Text != "" && tbSurname.Text != "")
        {
            SQLiteCommand CMD = DB.CreateCommand();
            CMD.CommandText = "insert into Personal(FIO) values(@Name);";
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = tbName.Text.ToUpper();
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SQLiteCommand CMD = DB.CreateCommand();
            CMD.CommandText = "insert into Personal(Age) values(@Age);";
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@Age", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = tbAge.Text.ToUpper();
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Обратите внимание: команда `insert into Personal(column1, column2) values(@value1)` некорректна: сколько параметров в первых скобках  — столько же должно быть и во вторых скобках.

Тут я пошёл по самому простому пути: просто убрал один параметр, но вам (как только данные начнут вставляться в таблицу) нужно будет либо сделать в таблице Personal вместо столбца FIO два столбца (Name и Surname) и делать в каждое поле вставку отдельно, либо делать вставку конкатенацией строк (это намного хуже, так как теряется информация о том, где имя, а где фамилия.

Поверьте, опыт работы с физлицами по всей России показывает, что у человека не всегда есть одно имя или что в ФИО будет только два пробела... Для ИП приходится вручную запрашивать, ибо машины не всегда корректно распознают эту информацию.

Comment: Пишет, что ';' недопустимый символ для этого выражения

Comment: @Роман Хм, значит я ошибся (студии под рукой нет, а [хотелось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749906/sql-logic-error-near-insert#comment1154576_749906) помочь с ответом) и вам нужно каждую отдельную команду выполнить именно как отдельную команду. Ссылки в помощь: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13677318/5752652), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696417/5752652). Если не разберетесь сами -- посмотрю завтра с работы и поправлю ответ.

Comment: Хм. Не обратил внимания, что у вас SQLiteCommand и сижу, гадаю, что у вас за пакет. Но вообще текущая версия должна уже заработать как надо.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Заставили пересесть на Access, вся работа с sql насмарку. Но спасибо вам за помощь!